# Google directions table not resizing correctly

Tags: html, css, google-maps, responsive-design

I have a problem with Google Directions based website that is not adapting to small mobile screens correctly. Here is the issue on the picture below:
[image]

In Chrome it is not shrinking below 395 px width which is a problem, because a lot of mobile phones have screen that is smaller width, then part of the information is not visible. In Firefox it doesn't go below 307 px width, this is not a huge issue but it would be good if it could go little bit more under this.
With Chrome inspect i found where the problem starts, it is on html table element with "adp-directions" class. Image is below.
[image]
I tried changing the width of this class to 100%, and to fixed width below 395px but it does not go under 395px. I tried putting !important in CSS to overwrite any other styles that i might not see, but still nothing... If you can please help me somehow because i am completely stuck here and don't know what else i could do... Here is the link to the site: [link](http://routenplaner-kostenlos-24h.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put media query for font size for smaller view

`@media (max-width:420px){table.adp-directions {
font-size: 12px !important;}}`
which will probably solve your question. But if you don't  like reducing font size do comment.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked adding `word-break` to the widest column, in order to break long descriptions, this allows column to reduce its width:

```
@media (max-width: 420px) {
    table.adp-directions tr td:nth-child(3) {
        word-break: break-all;
     }
}
```